# Website Layout doesn't change after changing the language

Tags: layout, theme, magento-1.9

So If I change the language of my Website - I will have the old static blocks in the default language like contact (In german it should be "Kontakt") I need to clear the cache all time to get the actual language layout. I'm using rwd theme 1.9+. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just for the test: if you disable the cache, the translation applies right after you switch language?

Comment: Yes your are right. Now it's working. So what should I do now? It's not good for the performance if I'm disable the cache.

Comment: Indeed... How did you made/installed ypur languages? Have a look there http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/75027/7773

Comment: Already installed the language pack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EE 1.14.2 / CE 1.9.2 block caching update has non-unique cache keys - duplicate content showing on frontend](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69215/ee-1-14-2-ce-1-9-2-block-caching-update-has-non-unique-cache-keys-duplicate)

Comment: OP, can you check @fschmengler's link and see if that solves your issue?